# Language Files Across Modules and Application

Tags: fuelphp

I was just looking to get some clarification on how FuelPHP handles language files across modules and the application directory. Does it merge all of them of the same name into one language array or if it finds it in the application does it just stop there?

If I was to create a foo.php language file in the application and in a module, will I have access to all the stuff in both files or just the one in application?

Comment: Answered my own question actually. Turns out that it won't automatically merge them (loading language files from a module requires the module name before the language file name), but you can manually load the files and it'll merge them into a single array at that point.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are in a module context, Lang::load('foo') will load the language file from the module, and will merge it with a global 'foo' if that exists.

You only have to explicitly specify the module using Lang::load('module::foo') if you are not in a module context, or you want to load something from another module then the active module.